# Equivalent of ruby obj.send in python

Tags: python, send

In ruby if I have an object obj, with a method called funcname, I can call the method using the following syntax
obj.send(funcname)

Is there something similar in python.

The reason I want to do this, that I have a switch statement where I set the funcname, and want to call it at the end of the switch statement.

Comment: Python doesn't have a switch statement. Moreover, generating function names at runtime is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @Rafe: It's not commonly needed, but there's nothing inherently evil about it.

Comment: Yes it doesn't but I still want to do it in and if-elif-else loop. I think I got my answer below.

Comment: You can always just assign the function: "f = obj.func", and call `f(args)` later on.  Python's method binding is good for that, when needed.

Answer (score 26):

```
getattr(obj, "name")(args)
```

​​​​

Answer (score 10):

hmmm... getattr(obj, funcname)(*args, **kwargs) ?

```
>>> s = "Abc"

>>> s.upper()
'ABC'

>>> getattr(s, "upper")()
'ABC'

>>> getattr(s, "lower")()
'abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the already mentioned `getattr()` builtin:

As an alternative to an if-elif-else loop you can use a dictionary to map your "cases" to the desired functions/methods:

```
# given func_a, func_b and func_default already defined
function_dict = {
    'a': func_a,
    'b': func_b  
}
x = 'a'
function_dict(x)() # -> func_a()
function_dict.get('xyzzy', func_default)() # fallback to -> func_c
```

Concerning methods instead of plain functions:

- you can just turn the above example into `method_dict` using  for example `lambda obj: obj.method_a()` instead of `function_a` etc., and then do `method_dict[case](obj)`
- you can use `getattr()` as other answers have already mentioned, but you only need it if you really need to get the method from its name.
- [operator.methodcaller()](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) from the stdlib is a nice shortcut in some cases: based on a method name, and optionally some arguments, it creates a function that calls the method with that name on another object (and if you provided any extra arguments when creating the methodcaller, it will call the method with these arguments)

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you prefer, `operator.methodcaller('foo')` is a function which calls `foo` on whatever you pass it. In other words,

```
import operator
fooer = operator.methodcaller("foo")
fooer(bar)
```

is equivalent to

```
bar.foo()
```

(I think this is probably the adjoint or dual in a suitable category. If you're mathematically inclined.)